# Has anyone managed to get group calls working with Kurento on iOS with IPv6 only networks as required by Apple?

Tags: ios, webrtc, kurento

For past few weeks I am trying to get the Kurento group calls to work with IPv6. However no success so far.

It seems that till M52 release of WebRTC (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5871), the WebRTC framework didn't support IPv6 for iOS. This was fixed in the M53 release of the iOS framework in August 2016.

However, it seems that with the latest M54 release of the framework group calls don't work with Kurento. First I tried to make it work with the official Kurento Group Call Java sample. In the end the video and audio from iOS goes to Chrome. But video and audio from Chrome doesn't come to iOS.

Then I found the Nubomedia Kurento iOS project. (https://github.com/nubomediaTI/Kurento-iOS). They have a sample for Kurento Room Project (Java Based) with iOS client. I managed to get it to run with Kurento 6.5 and 6.6 tagged commits. (For some reason the HEAD checkout doesn't run, even after adding 6.6.1-SNAPSHOT dependencies. It crashes with an exception during startup citing port conflict. Though I ensured that no other process was running on the same port.).

With IPv4 network, the Kurento Room Demo iOS project from Nubomedia runs properly and I am able to conference with one participant on Chrome and one participant on iOS.

However, on IPv6 network this demo fails. When I looked closely "WebRTC.framework" in the Nubomedia Kurento iOS project was checked in on Jul 29. Since M53 release of WebRTC.framework happened in August, it is understandable that this framework doesn't work with IPv6.

So I downloaded the M54 release of the framework from here: https://github.com/Anakros/WebRTC-iOS/releases/tag/13869.6.0

I replaced the older version of the framework in Nubomedia Kurento iOS project with this latest one. However, when I tried the Kurento Room Demo with this new build, the results were the same like I had obtained with the official Kurento Group Call Java sample. The video and audio from iOS goes to Chrome. But video and audio from Chrome doesn't come to iOS.

At this point, I don't have any clue on how to move forward to get Kurento Group Calls to work on iOS with IPv6. Hence the question:

Has anyone managed to get group calls working with Kurento on iOS with IPv6 only networks as required by Apple?

If yes, a few pointers on how to get it to work will be very helpful.

--

Note: I had asked this 4-5 days ago on Kurento Google Groups. But didn't get any answers. So trying here.

Comment: Hi @Pritam, At https://github.com/Anakros/WebRTC/issues/7 for ipv6 support, you mentioned that it works for you, but it is failing for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have trouble, do you have any solution?